# datagrid hyperlink

Tags: silverlight, datagrid, hyperlink

Within a datagrid I would like to put an hyperlink in the content of the cell

```
<sdk:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Code}" Header="Code" Width="40"  HeaderStyle="{StaticResource myStyle}" />
```

only if the content of the MyUrl property [of the same object that contains the Code I'm already binding against] is neither null or empty

How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you want this Column to be readonly you could use a DataGridTemplateColumn, put in a HyperLinkButton and bind IsHitTestVisible to MyUrl with a converter like this

```
<sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Code" Width="40">
    <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <HyperlinkButton IsHitTestVisible="{Binding Path=MyUrl,
                             Converter={StaticResource InvertNullOrEmptyConverter}}"
                             Content="{Binding Code}" NavigateUri="{Binding MyUrl}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

And in the Converter

```
public class InvertNullOrEmptyConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string valueToCheck = value as string;
        if (valueToCheck == null || valueToCheck == string.Empty)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```